# Windows 10, Keep Start Menu open when opening apps

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I would like to be able to open the start menu and then open several apps at the same time without the start menu closing after each click on an app. Is there a way to do this?

Apparently on previous Windows's you could just hold shift while clicking the program and the start menu would stay open. But that doesn't seem to work on Windows 10.

Comment: "Apparently on previous Windows's you could just hold shift while clicking the program and the start menu would stay open." - You actually confirm this because it does not work on any of my virtual machines running versions prior to Windows 8.  Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 don't have the traditional start menu so I didn't try those.

Comment: @Ramhound http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/keep-start-menu-from-closing-after-opening-applications/

if there's a way to do this in Win 10, I'd also love to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold down the windows key while selecting items.

Comment: Just tested this and confirmed that is does work. If you used the Win key to open the Start Menu you have to release it before the menu will open, but then pressing the key again and holding it you can click to open multiple applications.

Comment: Awesome! I wonder when this was added.